# Facebook PHP SDK - api returns empty

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to learn some facebook development because it seems people ask for facebook integration one way or another.

I am trying to get something as simple as my name to be echoed on screen using the PHP SDK and I cant seem to do it.

My code is extremely basic, just what's required for the

```
<?php
  require_once('src/facebook.php');

  $config = array(
    'appId' => '14283923YYYYYYY48',
    'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'allowSignedRequest' => false
  );

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
  $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
?>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>

  <?php
    if($user_id) {

        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
        echo "Name: " . $user_profile['name'];
        if (is_null($user_profile))
            echo "NULL";
        else echo "NOT NULL";
    }
  ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

The name does not show up, and as you can see I tested the $user_profile variable and it comes up NULL, so I assume that the api function doesn't work, doesn't return anything.

Is my code wrong? Or should I look elsewhere for the issue? Any tip or suggestion to solve the issue will be really helpful.

Comment: what is the result of `var_dump($user_profile)` ?

Comment: tried it just now, it's also NULL

Comment: It‘s `NULL` because you’re not attempting to log a user in. If you look at the [example](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php) you’ll see they have an `if`/`else` statement that creates a login/logout link depending on user status. A user needs to authenticate your app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a login facility to let the user explicitly allow use of their user ID, and create an access token. This can be done in the PHP SDK or JavaScript SDK (and can be both implemented for dual functionality).

Link:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/

** Please also view the following: [Facebook PHP SDK/Graph API - Returning MY name/info, but not anyone elses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222387/facebook-php-sdk-graph-api-returning-my-name-info-but-not-anyone-elses?rq=1)

Comment: I was trying it on my own account, and I was logged in and accepted the app requests. If I were to write echo $user_id, my FB ID would show in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if($user_id) {

    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
    echo "Name: " . $user_profile['name'];
    if (is_null($user_profile))
        echo "NULL";
    else echo "NOT NULL";
}

?>
```

change the partial section of code above

`$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');` to

```
$user profile = $facebook->api($user_id, 'GET')
```

then you would able to get the user profile whose using facebook login in your website

Hope this is help

Answer (score 0):

if you happened to work with a old project in codeigniter 3.x & deployed in aws ELB
in 2018 the facebook call back url mentioned in config or in fb app settings isn't enough,
with ssl, you need to manually edit `base_facebook.php` and replace `redirect_uri` from blank to your https url in the function `getAccessTokenFromCode()` argument,

```
protected function getAccessTokenFromCode($code, $redirect_uri = 'https://www.example.com/index/fblogin') {
    if (empty($code)) {
      return false;
    }
.....
```